# How to load texture from png in sdl2 useing SDL_image.h

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-image

I am trying to load an image into a texture using SDL_image.h however whenever I try to run the line of code that uses IMG_Load("./assets/snow.png) it just crashes the program without any error messages other than exit code -1073741515. My CMake file and parts of my CPP file are below. I think I might be missing a dll but cannot find one that I don't already have that I would need.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
SDL_Texture* playerTex;
void Game::init(const char *title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen) {
    int flags{0};
    //checks if fullscreen is true
    flags = fullscreen ? SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN : 0;
    //checks to make sure that the system is initialized correctly before making a window
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0) {
        std::cout << "subsystem running" << std::endl;

        window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
        //check if window was made successfully
        if (window) {
            std::cout << "window created" << std::endl;
        }

        //create render
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        if (renderer) {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
            std::cout << "Render created" << std::endl;
        }

        isRunning = true;
    } else {
        isRunning = false;
    }
    //TODO: why does this temp surface not set right prob issue with linking
    SDL_Surface* tempSurface = IMG_Load("./assets/snow.png");
    playerTex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,tempSurface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(tempSurface);
}

void Game::render() {
    //clear render buffer
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    //render texture
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer,playerTex,NULL,NULL);
    //render new stuff
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}
```

Here is my cmake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(learn_sdl2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/x64)

add_executable(learn_sdl2 main.cpp Game.cpp Game.h)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        SDL2main
        SDL2
        SDL2_image
        zlib1
        libpng16-16
        libjpeg-9)
```

Comment: Yes you are correct `-1073741515` is a dll not found: [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=-1073741515](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=-1073741515)

Comment: ***I think I might be missing a dll but cannot find one that I don't already have that I would need.*** Are the required dlls in a folder listed in your PATH environment variable or did you copy them to the same folder as your executable?

Comment: I figured it out I assumed that cmake auto included those files when i used target_link_libraries but i was wrong once I manually moved the files to the build dir it started working. Thank you @drescherjm

Comment: CMake does not automatically copy the dlls into the same folder as the executable. But you can have it with a bit of scripting. vcpkg does that using CMake scripts.